# Copy/Paste not working within Ubuntu 18.04 guest on VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I am unable to cut, copy and paste text *within* my Ubuntu 18.04 guest using VirtualBox on a MacOS Mojave 10.14.5 host. This is in addition to being unable to use Bidirectional clipboard between the guest and host. Guest Additions is installed.

Has anyone else encountered this? I am using the default keys under Input->Keyboard->Keyboard Settings. The commands do not work using my laptop keyboard and a USB keyboard. I am able to type with both keyboards and do key commands to bring up Terminal, etc.

The issue is repeatable on Linux kernels 5.0.0-23 and 4.16

Comment: Did you install the Extension Pack on the host? What version of VB are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer for an annoying problem. My problem was likely not knowing that copy/paste is different in Linux terminal than in the rest of the Linux system:

Cut - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>

Copy - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>

Paste - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>

see: https://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-cut-copy-and-paste-in-the-terminal-in-ubuntu

also answered here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/389788/340499

and here: [Is there a way to execute keyboard shortcuts from the terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1232611/is-there-a-way-to-execute-keyboard-shortcuts-from-the-terminal/1233004#1233004)