# Is there a way to execute keyboard shortcuts from the terminal?

Tags: xubuntu, gnome-terminal

I would like to execute a keyboard <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> shortcut from the terminal. In details, I would like to remap <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> on my keyboard. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> remapping it is not hard triggering <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> seems to be tricky

Is this possible?

Comment: Sounds like another [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/); what do you want to achieve? Also, did you do research on that topic, and what was the outcome?

Comment: @Murphy I would like to remap alt+c to ctrl+c on my keyboard.  alt+c remapping it is not hard triggering ctl+c seems to be tricky.

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: @Murphy https://askubuntu.com/questions/1232137/trigger-ctrlkey-keycode-or-hiragana-to-control  Yes XY problem basically.

Comment: @karel no it doesn't questions are related though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works unfortunately doesn't allow a linked command.

```
xdotool key ctrl+l
```

My plan was to use keyboard shortcuts under Ubuntu/Xubuntu to create autohotkey links but it fails to register the command.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer for an annoying problem. Copy/paste is different in Linux terminal than in the rest of the Linux system:

Cut - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>

Copy - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>

Paste - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>

Hope this helps.

see: https://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-cut-copy-and-paste-in-the-terminal-in-ubuntu

also answered here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/389788/340499

Comment: no this is not what I am looking for unfortunately.  I am trying to remap alt+c to ctrl+c.  Look at the posted answer it *should* work universally but it does not.

Comment: Are you using dedicated hardware or a VM?

Comment: dedicated hardware I have edited the question but how do I produce Ctrl+L as a keyboard shortcut?

Comment: Tricky problem. Have you tried clearing the cache? See Step 3 at the bottom: http://www.fascinatingcaptain.com/projects/remap-keyboard-keys-for-ubuntu/